# How to track the HTTP request and response time in jetty

Tags: http, time, jetty, response

I am trying to track the HTTP request and response time in Jetty. I have extended the jetty server and i am able to get the request timestamp using following snippet :

```
public void handle(HttpChannel connection) throws IOException,
        ServletException { 
    super.handle(connection); 

    connection.getRequest().getTimeStamp();
}
```

I need to get the exact time of the response for the request. 
How can i achieve it by extending jetty server ?
If any way of doing other than extending jetty. please let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to only be interested in the latency, do this.

The `RequestLog` mechanism is now to do this.

- Instantiate a new [`RequestLogHandler`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.5.v20151012/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/RequestLogHandler.java) and add it as the root of your server `Handler` tree (think nested, not collection).
- Add a custom implementation of [`RequestLog`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.5.v20151012/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog.java) to the `RequestLogHandler`
- In your custom `RequestLog.log(Request,Response)` method, [grab the `Request.getTimeStamp()` and work out the latency](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.5.v20151012/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L205-L214).

This approach is more durable to changes internally in Jetty, and does not require a fork Jetty + modify approach to work.